# Problem: Geometry Nodes Creating Instances Automatically

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, lattice, surface-deform

I'm trying to make a scene in Blender where I have several duplicate objects in a mesh and I need to make it expand without creating new clones. Would anyone know how?

I'm using a Lattice to expand the "mother mesh" but clones suddenly appear and disappear.

Video here: [Video](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/thbrsx/problem_geometry_nodes_creating_instances/)

[image: Example]

Comment: maybe you could place lattice modifier bellow GN modifier, but will be slower I guess

Comment: They blink in and out because you're changing the shape they're being spawned on so they redistribute. You could place the Lattice after GeoNodes, but you'd have to use a Realize Instances as well, it would be really slow and also distort the shapes, so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how elegant this is, if there's a much easier solution, but it looks to be working:

[image]

[image]

The reason your instances are blinking in and out is that your *Lattice* modifier comes before the *Geometry Nodes* modifier, so when *Lattice* changes the shape of your base mesh, the random placement of points also change slightly. So we need to put the *Lattice* after *Geometry Nodes*, but there's a problem: Lattices can only affect meshes, and your instances are not meshes—they're instances. You could use a *Realize Instances* node to make them into mesh first, but this would make it really, *really* slow, and it would also distort the distributed geometry instead of simply moving them with the surface.

So my solution was to use two Geometry Nodes instead of one, with a Lattice in between:

- With the first one, I'm taking the randomly distributed points and turning them into vertices (i.e. a mesh). I'm basically "locking them in", so to speak—they're no longer random after this point, just vertices in space. I'm also capturing their normals as an output attribute called "randompoints" (could be named anything).
- Then we put the *Lattice* on the stack. Since now I have a cloud of vertices, lattice can distort them safely, because they still contain the *Normal* information from the first Geometry Nodes modifier.
- Now I place the instances on those points, and orientate them with the normals information from before.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that right now!

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks a lot friend!
Cheers from Brazil!